# GCPとDjangoでbatch処理

Tags: python, django

お世話になります。

GCPとDjangoで定期的1日1回動かしたい、処理があります。

```
cron:
- description: "hoge"
  url: /batch/hoge
  schedule: every day 00:00
  timezone: Asia/Tokyo
```

`https://example.com/batch/hoge`(これをcurlで叩くと実行される)

というようなものを作ったのですが、こちらのcron.yamlをdeployしてしまうと、外部アクセスがあったときもこの処理がされてしまいます。

これを防ぐためにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

普通は、`/batch/xxx`などにスクリプトを書いて、crontabで動かすと思うのですが、GCPでもそのようなことはできるのでしょうか。またこのスクリプトにはDjangoの機能は使っておらず、素のpythonスクリプトになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCPのCronはリクエストヘッダーに自動でパラメーターを付加してくれます。

> X-Appengine-Cron: true

リクエストの結果を調査して、上記のヘッダーがなければ処理がされないようにアプリケーションを作ってはどうでしょう。

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/cronref?hl=ja#cron_requests